# C++. Можно ли загружать значения с сервера.

Tags: c++

Можно ли загружать значения переменных с сервера? Например из .txt файлов на нём.

Comment: Ну, это если сервер отдаст вам файл.

Comment: @VladD, а если не отдаст, то можно попробовать отобрать. Нечего файлы «зажимать»

Comment: Кстати, в том виде, в котором сейчас вопрос, я могу дать Вам следующий ответ: «Спросите у сервера, мы то Вам может дать разрешение, но вдруг сервер не согласится»

Comment: @ixSci: «Слышь, файлы есть? Дай txt погонять! А если найду?» (ц)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string content;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::ostringstream out;
    out << res;

    content = out.str();
  }

  std::cout << content << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Компилируем

```
g++ -lcurl -o example example.cpp
```

Запускаем:

```
$ ./example 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
```